# How to find indices for consecutive zeros at the end of the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have a list something like this,

```
test = [4, 7, 8, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0]
```

I want to get the indices of consecutive zero's at the end of a list. I want either the starting index of zero at the end or all three indices. Check my desired output.

Desired output :

```
[9, 10, 11] (or) 9 (just 9 would also suffice)
```

I tried `np.where` but it returns indices of all the zero's.

```
np.where((np.array(test)==0))
```

Note: I need a efficient solution because the size of my list is very large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that pattern of trailing zeros confirmed, we can do use an array and NumPy tools based method, like this -

```
len(test)-np.equal(test,0)[::-1].argmin()
```

If you need all zeros indices until that index -

```
In [100]: mask = np.equal(test,0)

In [101]: idx = len(test)-mask[::-1].argmin()

In [102]: np.flatnonzero(mask[:idx])
Out[102]: array([5, 6, 7])
```

To explain the index getting part, let's break it down into steps -

```
# Mask of zeros
In [100]: mask = np.equal(test,0)

In [101]: mask
Out[103]: 
array([False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False,
        True,  True,  True])

# Flip it
In [104]: mask[::-1]
Out[104]: 
array([ True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False,
       False, False, False])

# Get the first index of False ones, which would be the last non-zero
# value from original array. Note that this is on flipped version of input
In [105]: mask[::-1].argmin()
Out[105]: 3

# Get the original index position by subtracting from the length of it
In [106]: len(test)-mask[::-1].argmin()
Out[106]: 9
```

Comment: Thank you. Just one more small help which I didn't added in the question. Is it possible to get the indices of zeros in between ignoring the last three consecutive zero's. I'm looking for a output like `[5, 6, 7]`.

Comment: Can you tell me how this is actually working. I mean `np.equal(test,0)[::-1]` this returns `array([ True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False])` and how is then `argmin` returning 3 here? How is it deciding minimum value index with Boolean array.

Comment: @user_6396 Added some explanation there.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it:

```
test = [4, 7, 8, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0]

res_index = 0

for item in test[-1::-1]:
    if item == 0:
        res_index += 1
    else:
        break

print(len(test) - res_index)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure python almost one liner solution, without calling methods, building stacks, creating lists and other inefficiencies:

```py
>>> size = len(test)
>>> while size > 0 and data[size-1] == 0: size -= 1
```

Then you just retrieve your integer index value

```py
>>> size
9
```

Comment: Well NumPy functions and array works well on large data. Of course, there's an overhead on creating the array data. So, short-circuiting based methods could benefit from the scenario when traversed from the other end and looking for first non-zero if it's close by. I am not aware of - `building stacks, creating lists and all sort of inefficiencies` part that you are referring to.

Comment: I edited that part anyway so it does not harm anyone.